# Window Well Woes--Can I remove a window well here?

Tags: basement, windows

Ugh!  Window wells...  So we built a semi-custom Shea home in Colorado.  Walk out basement has several windows above grade.  Shea put in a window well that covers nearly half of the window.  I get the feeling that Shea didn't give individual thought about which windows needed wells.  Anyway, the grade, as you can see in the photo, is below the window sill at least 6 inches.  The window sits on concrete [image].  There is a small paver-type retaining wall right next to the edge of the well, where the air conditioner sits.  My question is this: Can I remove the window well, making sure that the retaining wall remains intact?

Comment: Good chance they were put in because of local building code said so, instead of something fun to do.  Will need to ask local building department and/or local fire department(it might be an escape path for fire victims).

Comment: Since the windows are at or above grade the wells may be there to prevent rock damage, I would verify the local requirements prior to removal as it looks like it was poured separately from the foundation so it is there for protection or a code requirement.

Comment: Do you live in a Flood Zone ?

Comment: Not a flood zone--we are on top of a hill.

Comment: This is a walk-out basement.  There is a french door 10 feet away in the same non-partitioned room, so not sure why a fire-victim would climb through this window.  Even if they did climb through, they would be stepping down to the ground and would trip over the window well to escape.  Thanks for the responses.  Looks like the safe answer is to ask the local building department about code...